# When I am passing this in my view it just displays the html markup. Do I need to pass it in a template tag?

Tags: django

## views

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo(request):
    cal = HTMLCalendar()
    calendar = cal.formatmonth(2013, 6)
    return render(request, 'foo.html', {calendar = calendar})
```

## template

```
{{calendar}}
```

It just display the html makrup. Not the calendar. So do I need to pass it as a template tag?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Python, and I haven't ever worked with Django, but it might be that your dictionary syntax is off.  It should be `{calendar: calendar}` if I remember correctly.  If I'm mistaken, disregard!  You may need a string around the dictionary key too: `{'calendar': calendar}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar
from django.shortcuts import render

def foo(request):
    cal = HTMLCalendar()
    calendar = cal.formatmonth(2013, 6)
    return render(request, 'foo.html', { 'calendar': calendar})
```

or you could even do `dict(calendar=calendar)`

and in template

```
{{calendar|safe}}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now. Do you mind telling me what the problem was?

Comment: you need to use the `safe` filter for HTML to be rendered in a django template. See the documentation Here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe Also, there was a small error in the syntax